# Should I follow the advice of my Uraldan magician and keep all my magic in reserve?

Tags: king-of-dragon-pass

I am looking at the screen for the first Sacred Time in Dragon Pass of my freshly generated "King Heort exhorted us to get along with our neighbours" Elmali-Jested's-Wake-Lhankor-build peace clan.  Our god talkers augured that for year 1330:

> the signs for calving looked bad

I expected the consensus to be something about sacrificing to the gods.  My ring warrior Orlanthi could not have expressed the thought better when he said:

> We must put magic into mysteries so we can learn the proper rituals for aiding cattle fertility

But the Uraldan ring magician disagrees.  She says of our seven points:

> Don't allocate anything, our stockpiled clan magic is inadequate.

Is she crazy or inspired?  I'm not going to allocate any magic until I've decided which, but I don't see how failing to allocate at least two points among mysteries, war and diplomacy can be anything but foolish.

Comment: You are unlikely to be able to satisfy all of your advisors every time, or even most of the time…

Comment: @DavidDunham Not putting magic into mysteries in the first year doesn't sound like good advice.  But I was wondering if the clan cattle fertility expert might have special insight into the cattle fertility augurs, the same way that the ring seems to have an inkling of the rainbow event before it comes.

Comment: Yes, she does. But she also sees everything through her own viewpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd lean towards your viewpoint.  Allocating magic to the tasks you plan on accomplishing during the year is a very good thing, as it greatly increases the chances of those tasks succeeding.  In fact, I would not even attempt a Hero Quest without putting all the magic I could into Quests.

On the other hand, having a positive magic reserve is a good thing, as that improves your luck during random events.  It follows that a negative magic reserve is a bad thing, so it isn't a bad idea to keep a point or two in reserve, to prevent a negative reserve from occurring.  All seven, though?  Not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Not much chance of success in quest in first year as Elmali clan without learning quest mysteries in any case.  But "calving" issues might be code for a chaos event, and magic points might help tracking that down.  Still would want war/hunting points for that fight.  Will play with points allocated to just mysteries, war, diplomacy & crops, leaving 3 in stockpile.

Comment: Accepted: Uralda magician, with flying warriors event, says we can't share any of our 3 points of clan magic because "We have no magic to give them."  She is a miser with the magic stockpile, I think.